# an unknown empty string gets added to localStorage in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I'm using localStorage to keep a list of items added to cart, this is my function for the add to cart button in spread out components,

```
addToCart(item_id){
console.log("clicked: "+item_id);
this.dataTransmit.changeId(item_id);
}
```

and this is the component that collects all the items added from different components to the localStorage,

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.dataTransmit.currentItemId.subscribe(itemID => {

  this.updateStorage(itemID);

});
 //localStorage.clear();
}

updateStorage(itemID) {

let key = JSON.stringify(itemID);
localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(1));
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
  let key = localStorage.key(i);
  console.log(key);
}
}
```

somehow my console log retrieves an " " as a key out of nowhere, and I realized the issue get fixed when you uncomment the `localStorage.clear()` function in the code above, but using it is not an option obviously cause I don't want to clear my localStorage every time the page reloads, and I also assigned a clear() function to a button and made sure my localStorage is empty to begin with, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what version of angular are you using ?

Comment: angular 9, I'm not sure if it's angular to blame though

Comment: What is `itemID` here? Is it an object?

Comment: a string variable but consists of numbers

Comment: If it's already a string then what is the purpose of `JSON.stringify(itemID)`?

Comment: I'm sorry that's a leftover code from my previous implementation, which I passed itemID as a number, removing it doesn't fix the issue though just logs and empty space without the " "

Comment: You should actually pass a `DOMString` as a key. Try to use `String(itemID)`.

Comment: Doesn't affect it since it's already a string,  just assigns a blank space without the " " surrounding it

Comment: You said "passed itemID as a number". Please do a console log of itemID and it's type using (`typeof itemID`) and update it in the question.